# Error when running helloworld + classpath problem

Tags: java, classpath

I am compiling helloworldapp with no errors.

I am running 
java helloworldapp
on windows

CLASSPATH:
.;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib;

JAVA_HOME:
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7

path includes
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\

Result:

```
C:\Users\k\Desktop\abcl-bin-0.26.2>java helloworldapp
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: helloworldapp (wrong
name: HelloWorldApp)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
............etc
```

So ok, for some reson it couldn't find the classes, so I am trying to do it manually.

```
C:\Users\k\Desktop\abcl-bin-0.26.2>java -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib" helloworldapp
Error: Could not find or load main class helloworldapp

C:\Users\k\Desktop\abcl-bin-0.26.2>java -cp C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib; helloworldapp
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Java\jre7\lib;
```

What am I doing wrong?
I have looked at several forums, but they weren't particularly helpful.

Update, I got past the helloworld stage. 
Now the real problem

```
import org.armedbear.lisp.*;

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] argv)
    {
    try
        {
        Main thisObject = new Main();
        Interpreter interpreter = Interpreter.createInstance();
        interpreter.eval("(load \"lispfunctions.lisp\")");
        org.armedbear.lisp.Package defaultPackage = 
            Packages.findPackage("CL-USER");
        Symbol voidsym = 
            defaultPackage.findAccessibleSymbol("VOID-FUNCTION");
        Function voidFunction = (Function) voidsym.getSymbolFunction();
        voidFunction.execute(new JavaObject(thisObject));
        }
    catch (Throwable t)
        {
        System.out.println("exception!");
        t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public int addTwoNumbers(int a, int b)
    {
    return a + b;
    }
}
```

I tried both

```
C:\Users\k\Desktop\abcl-bin-0.26.2>java -cp abcl.jar Main
Error: Could not find or load main class Main

C:\Users\k\Desktop\abcl-bin-0.26.2>java -cp abcl.jar main
Error: Could not find or load main class main
```

The abcl.jar is located in the same folder

Some more trials and errors

```
C:\Users\k\Desktop\abcl-bin-0.26.2>java -cp .:abcl.jar Main
Error: Could not find or load main class Main

C:\Users\k\Desktop\abcl-bin-0.26.2>java Main -cp .:abcl.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/armedbear/lisp/Li
spObject
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.armedbear.lisp.LispObject
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
```

Comment: What happens when you run `java HelloWorldApp` ?

Comment: @sabof, you shouldn't change the question to ask a new one, you should ask a new question separate from this

Comment: I thought they were too similar to open a new post

Comment: do you need to set the class path? by default java should use the working directory?

Comment: "java Main"
gives me a NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/armedbear/lisp/Li
spObject

Comment: "org/armedbear/lisp/Li spObject" with a space, or is that a typo?

Comment: yes it's a typo. I assume that since LispObject is mentioned, it means that abcl.jar has loaded. I also have successfully compiled and run other java classes, so maybe the problem has to do with abcl.jar itself

Comment: run the command "jar -tvf abcl.jar" this will list all of the classes in the jar, if LispObject is missing then there is a problem with the Jar

Comment: @sabof C:\Users\k\Desktop\abcl-bin-0.26.2\ contains the abcl.jar and Main.class?

Comment: @sabof did the Main.java file compile correctly? delete the Main.class file then recompile it

Comment: Yes, I have already tried that several times. No messages or errors during compilation

Comment: I have found a solution, it's
java -cp .;abcl.jar Main (semicolon), thanks for the help

Comment: @sabof are you running windows or linux?

Comment: @sabof, I have updated my answer. On windows a classpath should be separated by a ; rather than a :

Comment: It's been flagged that you're adding too many new problems to this question and it's becoming confusing to know what you are really asking. Please ask *one* question at a time. It's ok to break your problem down into multiple question, just don't lump them in the same post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write a class in java, the name of the file must match the name of the class.

```
class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }

}
```

must be saved as HelloWorldApp.java
It must match the case i.e. helloworldapp.java would not work.

When you need to run the class, you must refer to it using the correct case.

```
java HelloWorldApp
```

but not

```
java helloworldapp
```

If you are referencing a JAR then you need to add it to your classpath. By default the classpath consists of the files in the current working directory. 
On windows the classpath is a semi-colon (;) separated list, on Linux and Mac OSX it is a colon (:) separated list.

To include the JAR in the classpath you must run the following...

```
java -cp .:myjar.jar MyMainClass
```

where **myjar.jar** is the JAR file you want to reference and **MyMainClass** is the class that contains your **public static void main** method.